# Matching identical items in different database lists

Tags: mysql, sql, database, pattern-matching

I'm writing an app where people can upload lists of movies they own.

My database will probably have the following structure:

> USER
>
> - UserID - unique identifier
> - Name - user's full name
> - Email - user's email
>
> MOVIE
>
> - UserID - user who owns this movie
> - MovieID - movie unique identifier (I'm currently using IMDB's code)

So "Movie" has many-to-one relationship with "User"

What I would like to do is to recommend a user of a random "movie buddy". Basically, I would like to find 2 users who own the same movie (so I'm trying to match 2 user's list to find matching movies) and then showing him a message similar to **"Hey, XYZ is a fan of The Dark Knight Rises as well!"**

The match should be random with a simple filter for already seen suggestions (I don't want a user to get the same suggestion twice for both the same buddy and movie, but it's ok to suggest him the same buddy for a DIFFERENT movie - assuming they both own 2 different movies).

I don't know how to perform this kind of match using MySQL. I'm also open to other suggestion for a database if one is more appropriate (I've heard about graph databases, but never used any myself)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finding users with the same movie ID is pretty simple its just three JOINs

```
FROM
    User u
    INNER JOIN movie m
    ON u.UserID = m.UserID
    INNER JOIN moive BuddyMovie
    ON m.moiveID = BuddyMovie.MovieID
       and u.UserID <> Buddy.UserID --Don't want to be your own Buddy
    INNER JOIN User BuddyUser
    ON BuddyMovie.UserID = BuddyUser.UserID
WHERE
    u.UserID = 123  -- For a given user
    and m.MovieID = 345 -- Optionally For a given movie
```

Getting a random user you just need to add `ORDER BY RAND()`

If you want only two just add `LIMIT 2`

Making sure you don't get the same Buddy Twice will require that you keep track of which buddies were all ready shown which goes beyond the scope of a single question.